# From code, how to get favorites explorer shortcuts in Windows 7

Tags: windows-explorer

In Windows 7, there's a Favorites tree that appears in Explorer that the user can dynamically add items to.

How can I retrieve these shortcuts from code?

In c#, I know I can do the following:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites)`

but that seems to be an entirely different Favorites folder.

I've googled around but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

You want [FOLDERID_Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I don't think there is a .net constant for this but you can PInvoke [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), use COM (CLSID_KnownFolderManager/IKnownFolderManager) or the [.net WinAPI Codepack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

Comment: I haven't tried the Codepack (second to last day on my current job so I know I won't be getting around to it), but PInvoking SHGetKnownFolderPath() with the GUID for favorites defined in the link did not provide me with any user-added folders to the explorer favorites tree. To clarify, I can add items to my Favorites tree via Windows Explorer, but I do not know where these Favorites additions are stored or how to access them programatically without trolling the registry.

Comment: Not favorites, links... (Somewhat confusing)